# TypeError: _parse_args() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size' for gamma distribution

Tags: python, scipy, gamma-distribution

I'm trying to plot Gamma(alpha=scale=29, beta=size=3), but I'm getting the error TypeError: _parse_args() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size' for `y1`. I'm following the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html) for gamma distributions and there's a size parameter for the gamma distribution, so I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gamma
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace (0, 100, 200) #start, stop, num of samples
y1 = gamma.pdf(x, scale = 29, size = 3) #PRODUCES ERROR HERE
plt.plot(x, y1, "-", label=(r'$\alpha=1, \beta=1$')) 

plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$')
plt.title('Gamma Distributions (' + r'$y=Gamma(\alpha + k, \beta + 1)$' +')')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

**Error Message**
[image]

Comment: Show the full stack trace.

Comment: probably a version thing. the page you linked to is for ver 0.14.0
run `scipy.__version__` to see which version you actually have

Comment: @user2357112 updated.

Comment: @Nullman oh I found scipy version on terminal (0.18.1), but I'm running python on Jupyter notebooks, so would scipy version 18.1 still run on Jupyter notebooks?

Comment: afaik jupyter uses the same libraries your regular python uses, but you can just open a notebook and type `scipy.__version__` to see the version jupyter uses

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation for `gamma.pdf()` the size parameter doesn't exist:

[scipy.stats.gamma](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html)

```
gamma.pdf(x, a) = lambda**a * x**(a-1) * exp(-lambda*x) / gamma(a)
```

In particular, looking at the methods in the documentation:

```
gamma.pdf(x, a, loc=0, scale=1)
```

so you can play with `loc`, `scale` but not `size`.
Instead you could use that parameter in

```
gamma.rvs(a, size=100)
```

just to make an example.
In brief, you're not supposed to have

```
y1 = gamma.pdf(x, scale = 29, size = 3)
```

as you can see in the docs.

Look at the methods listed in [scipy.stats.gamma](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html) and you will see `gamma.pdf()` method doesn't have size parameter that you can call in the way you did as I've shown before.

Comment: Is `a` is the scale of the gamma distribution (beta)?

Comment: Then how do I translate `y1 = gamma.pdf(x, scale = 29, size = 3) ` into a gamma distribution with parameters alpha = scale = 29 and beta = size = 3 in python? Doesn't `rvs` return a random variable, NOT  a probability distribution?

Comment: `a` is the "shape" parameter of the gamma distribution. `scale` is the scale parameter.

Comment: @RobertKern is right. Please, have a look at the possible parametrizations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution .

Comment: @RobertKern @fedepad I understand the parameters of a gamma distribution. My question is I want to PLOT a gamma distribution with ALPHA = 29  and BETA = 3 (i.e. Gamma(29,3)). How do I do this if the python gamma function only has parameters `a` and `x` and the size parameter doesn't exist?

Comment: What do you mean by `alpha` and `beta`? There are many different conventions for naming the parameters of a gamma distribution. `alpha` and `beta` don't mean anything by themselves. `scipy.stats.gamma.pdf()` uses `scale` for the scale parameter and `a` for the shape parameter of the gamma distribution. From your attempt, I assume that you mean `alpha` to be the scale parameter and `beta` to be the shape parameter. In that case, plot `gamma.pdf(x, scale=29, a=3)` against `x`.